# Borrar los elementos de un recycler view

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de tareas en Kotlin con Android Studio en la que utilizo un recycler view, en ella se puede añadir una tarea que se queda añadida en el recycler view y que luego se puede pulsar en ella para ver información en detalle.

El problema que tengo es que aunque mediante varios bucles y el preference manager como veréis he conseguido guardar las tareas creadas, al mantener pulsado con el setOnLongClickListener en vez borrarse el elemento que pulso, lo que sucede es que se me borra el ultimo elemento añadido y he probado de todo pero no consigo que se borre el que pulso.

Seria de gran ayuda que alguien me dijese que estoy haciendo mal y que debo cambiar, si es necesario estoy dispuesto a dar un pequeño incentivo económico a quien me ayude.

A continuación dejo tanto el mainActivity como el adapter que uso.

MainActivity:

```html
package com.kyler.myaccounts

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    val plusButtonCode = 1

    lateinit var tareaAdapter: TareaAdapter

    val key = "contadorArray"

    val tareas = ArrayList<Tarea>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstance: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)


        var mbottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView? = null

        mbottomNavigation = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottomNavigation) as BottomNavigationView
        mbottomNavigation!!.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            if (item.itemId == R.id.home_button) {
                val intent1 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent1)
            }
            if (item.itemId == R.id.plus_button) {
                val intent2 = Intent(this, PlusActivity::class.java)
                intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivityForResult(intent2, plusButtonCode)
            }
            if (item.itemId == R.id.graphics_button) {
                val intent3 = Intent(this, GraphicsActivity::class.java)
                intent3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent3)
            }
            true
        }



        val tareas = ArrayList<Tarea>()


        tareaAdapter = TareaAdapter(tareas,this)


        recycler_view.adapter = TareaAdapter(tareas, this)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        var contador_Array: Int = prefs.getInt(key, 0)

        var x = 0
        if(contador_Array != null && contador_Array != 0){

            while (x < contador_Array) {
                var y: String = x.toString()
                var z: String = x.toString()
                var miNombre: String? = prefs.getString(y, "")

                if (miNombre != null && miNombre != "" ){
                    tareas.add(x, Tarea(miNombre))
                }

                x++
            }

        }


    }
 //Agregar item
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == plusButtonCode){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val tareaDescripcion = data!!.extras!!["editText_tarea"]

                val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

                tareaAdapter.agregarTarea(Tarea(tareaDescripcion as String))

                //Almacenamos la información de la clase Suscripcion
                val editor = prefs.edit()
                var x = 0
                var total = tareaAdapter.itemCount

                println(tareaAdapter.itemCount)


                while (x < total) {
                    var y: String = x.toString()

                    editor.putString(y, tareaAdapter.guardarDatos(x))
                    editor.putInt(key, total)
                    editor.apply()
                    x++
                }

            }
        }
    }



}
```

Adapter del recycler view:

```html
package com.kyler.myaccounts


import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.plus_layout.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.tarea_item.view.*

val key = "contadorArray"

const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.kyler.myaccounts.nombre_tarea"


class TareaAdapter(public var tareas : ArrayList<Tarea>, private var contexto: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TareaAdapter.TareaViewHolder>() {


    fun agregarTarea(tarea: Tarea){
        tareas.add(tarea)
        notifyItemInserted(itemCount)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TareaViewHolder {
        return TareaViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.tarea_item, parent, false), contexto)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return tareas.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TareaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.boton_tarea.text = tareas[position].nombre
        println(tareas[position].nombre)
        holder.bind(tareas[position],tareas)
        guardarDatos(position)

        holder.itemView.boton_tarea.setOnLongClickListener {

            val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contexto)

            var x = 0
            var total = tareas.size

            val editor = prefs.edit()


            tareas.remove(Tarea(tareas[position].nombre))


            editor.putInt(key, tareas.size)

            editor.apply()


            println(tareas.size)

            val intent = Intent(contexto, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
            contexto.startActivity(intent)
            true
        }


    }

    fun guardarDatos (n:Int) : String{
        return tareas[n].nombre
    }



    //Abrir actividad con el nuevo item
    class TareaViewHolder(private var vista: View,private var contexto:Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista){
        fun bind (tarea: Tarea, tareas: ArrayList<Tarea>){
            vista.boton_tarea.setOnClickListener{
                contexto.startActivity(Intent(contexto, tarea_info::class.java).putExtra(
                   EXTRA_MESSAGE,tarea.nombre))

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Si alguien necesita algún archivo mas de la aplicación para poder resolver el problema que me lo diga, que no tendré problema en subirlo.

De antemano agradezco enormemente la ayuda que se me proporcione.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deberias hacer es notificar cual es el elemento que acabas de borrar

```
tareas.remove(position)
notifyItemRemoved(position)
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Lo que haces acá es remover el elemento tarea de la position que te devuelve el array, no es necesario que pases el objecto que quieres borrar, simplemente la posicion del array donde esta dicho elemento

Comment: Hola, intente lo que me dijiste y funciona hasta que la activity se actualiza y saca los datos de la memoria del preference manager, utilizando el bucle while que hay dentro del onCreate del main actvity en el que uno por uno los vuelve a cargar al array, y ahi es entonces donde vuelve a pasar lo de que se ha borrado tan solo el ultimo y no el que pulse.